# Div contains absolute positioned element therefore has no height

Tags: css, css-position, jquery-cycle

I'm using `cycle.js` to create a rotating banner. The cycle works by using `position:absolute` on the banner link.

Problem is, the containing div now has a height of zero, and thus the content below overlaps and is hidden.

How can I make the div `slideshow` have height? Needs to be responsive so cannot be a set height.

```
<div id="feature">
   <div class="slideshow" style="position: relative;">
        <a href="/guarantees.aspx" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
              display: none; z-index: 2; opacity: 0; width: 682px; height: 258px;">
           <img alt="" src="/images/mobile/banner1.jpg">
        </a>
        <a href="/fencing.aspx" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; 
            display: block; z-index: 3; opacity: 1; width: 682px; height: 259px;">
           <img alt="" src="/images/mobile/banner2.jpg">
        </a>
   </div>
   <div id="pageNav">
        <a href="#" class="">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="#" class="activeSlide">&nbsp;</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why cannot it be with set height? Have you tried percentage? Like `height:100%`?

Comment: @MaximGrishin height 100% does not work (still outputs 0 height) it cannot be set as the height depends on the width of the browser, so needs to expand to the given content within the div.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your problem? I`ve just added background-color to your second `a` tag and it is not hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/A5SJJ/

Comment: And it seems to me that it's kinda strange that you set height to your `a` tags and want it to be responsive.

Comment: I am not setting heights. The heights are created by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your only option is to bind events handler to [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [`resize`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) in order to set the `height` of `.slideshow` through Javascript by detecting your `window` width (or with your current image `height` if you so wish; Cycle offers a [pretty complete API](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) through which you could for example bind a callback function on changing of image to set your new height).

Since you are using Javascript to handle your current image dimensions anyways, this shouldn't come as a problem.

In any case, perhaps you should consider then using another slider plugin (or write your own function) that addresses your needs by not using a `position: absolute`. Cycle is quite old and probably wasn't build with a *responsive* mindset (I know that the same dev is working on [**Cycle 2**](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/) with a more modern approach).